# Nginx listening on different port but not accessible from outside

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, web-server, port

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

I have both Apache and Nginx running. Apache is listening on port 80 and that is why I want to make Nginx listen on different port, in this example it would be 90.

Below is the configuration at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` (and yes, the symlink is created):

```
server {
    listen 90 default_server;

    server_name www.example.com.pl;
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I have firewall configured and the `ufw status` shows:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
90                         ALLOW       Anywhere
...
```

I have also added the rule to iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:90
...
```

The `nmap 12.34.567.89` shows:

```
Nmap scan report for www.example.com.pl (12.34.567.89)
Host is up (0.00046s latency).
Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
90/tcp   open  dnsix
...
```

And below is the output from `netstat -tulpn`:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:90              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN        26902/nginx
...
```

`index.html` contains `<h1> Nginx TEST </h1>`, and when I execute `wget www.example.com.pl:90` from the server, I download the file without any problem. However, when I try to `telnet` the URL from local computer, it can't connect. When I enter `www.example.com.pl:90` in the browser, it shows `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. Everything indicates that the port 90 is closed to outside connections. And that's where I got lost. Any ideas or suggestions?

PS. Please be forgiving, this is my first post :)